# How to set memory the master node more than workers nodes' memory in H2O?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, h2o

In my algorithm, master node needs more memory (say 20GB) while the worker nodes need much less memory (say 3GB). However, as far as I know, in H2O it is only possibly to set the master node the same memory as worker nodes using `-mapperXmx`.

In Apache Spark, it is possible to specify the driver memory with `--driver-memory` argument. However, I have **not** been able to find a equivalent way to set "master/driver" node's memory in H2O.

I am running H2O (**not** Sparkling Water) on a Hadoop cluster (essentially on a YARN cluster) using this command:
`hadoop jar h2o-hadoop-3/h2o-cdh6.3-assembly/build/libs/h2odriver-3.33.1.jar -nodes 5 -mapperXmx 3g -output my/output/dir/on/hdfs`. This way I am able to specify worker nodes' memory as 3GB. However, I could not find the argument to specify the master node's memory.  Is it possible to set the master node 20GB?

Comment: I respectfully request you reword your answer to emphasize that you are looking for H20 settings to adjust the master.   (Spark has similar worker/master/driver terminology and its not clear from you question what you are looking for help with.)

Comment: If you are talking H20 sparkling water you should also reference if you are running internally or externally.

Comment: @MattAndruff Thank you for your response. I have edited my questions and added some details about my settings and cluster environment.

Answer (score 0):

The master node is also known as the "driver" so yes, you can set the driver memory: `spark.driver.memory`  Here's a [complete list of settings](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) you can tweak.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question is about H2O.ai not Apache Spark

Comment: My bad. My question is unclear and misleading. I have added more details to it.